# How can I unhide the system tray while other windows are maximised?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, notification-area

Sometime in the last few weeks my Windows 10 taskbar stopped UN-hiding unless all windows are minimized. If i have any windows open over the desktop such as Firefox (or any other window): I now have to minimize that window first. This can be frustrating when I have a lot of windows open and have to minimize all of them to hover and un-hide. I have windows 10 1909.How can I  un-hide the taskbar while other windows are maximized? I'm sure that this is not the normal default behavior but is there a way for me to make it so when I hover over the bottom of the screen my tray will pop up (even when there are open windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through all my 38 programs that start with Windows. And there was one program (One that draws Screen Gestures) interfering with the proper auto-hide functionality. I eliminated it and all is well again.

---

a

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what your desired requirement is, but you van change the visibility behaviour of the taskbar, by right clicking on the taskbar, and selecting "Taskbar settings" (usually at the bottom of the list that pops up).

In there change the setting until you have the desired effect.

To have my taskbar always visible (unless I make a application full screen (different to maximised)) I have:
Lock taskbar on
auto hide desktop off
auto hide tablet off
use small buttons off
Use peek to preview off

I think these are the only ones that will effect what you need (from a quick review),

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes thank you for the quick response. I do not want the taskbar "Always Visible". I want the system tray to hide and reappear as normal (move mouse to touch bottom of screen). This works if I am looking at My desktop. However if a window covers the bottom of the desktop my tray does not reappear. It used to. I have auto hide desktop set on, auto hide tablet on, use small buttons off, Use peek to preview off.

Comment: Sad to say, my experience is, it's just buggy, if I turn on auto hide, windows disappear behind the taskbar, and it never hides. which is why mine is always on. I never found a solid solution for getting it to work, so I just gave up, i've done a lot of pc support over the years, it works on some not on others was my eventual conclusion.